# <iframe> doesn't send php _POST values to the viewing website

Tags: php, post, iframe, get

So, I made a " browse" website for my affiliations working with iframes, but then i got a problem.

The website seems to be displaying correctly, but when i click something on the website iframed, it doesn't look like sending the _POST requests to the website. So it only "refresh" the frame without sending anything.

this is the view page

```
<IFRAME SRC="/filter.php?link=link_goes_here" WIDTH=1000 HEIGHT=500>
If you see that message, your browser isn't supported to use iframes. 
</IFRAME>
```

Due to the fact some websites have "inappropriate contents" i use a filter to delete the contents which i find inappropriate, so this is the filter page:

```
$link=trim($_GET["link"]);
$data = file_get_contents($link);

$replace_inappropriate="bad words goes here";
$replace_with="";
$data=str_replace($replace_inappropriate,$replacewith,$data);

echo $data;
```

The code works, i can see the website, and the inappropriate words goes away, but all the FORMS with method _POST (if the site has any), does not work. It just "refresh" the page without process it.

How fix this?

Comment: file_get_contents will by default do a GET request to a page. You can create a [stream_context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) to setup post parameters or use curl to request the page. Sounds like what you want/should do though is just find a proxy script and run that.

Comment: Still no clue on how to do that..

Comment: Bytheway, I cannot use a "proxy script" found on the internet, cause most of time times, is full of sh.t .. and i don't want the users to appear with my server IP

Comment: file_get_contents will make it look like "the users appear with [your] server IP". Your server is sending out the request to get the page, modifying it and displaying it to the user. And if you read the manual page I posted above and go to the stream_context_create page, there are examples on how to post to a server using file_get_contents.

Comment: Well, I dont know how to do that, and redirecting me to a function i dont even know, won't help me at all... would've be more appreciated if actually you made an example, instead of just tell me "hey use this".

Comment: I'm sure you would have liked for me to just do this for you. Instead I told you where to go that has a *complete working example* on how to post to a page. I could copy and paste that for you if you are too busy to look it up for yourself.

Comment: I don't want you to do it for me, all I asked is an example. I'm a PHP beginner, not professional nor a expert. I learn through examples. Which is the best way to learn at things